# Visual Studio 2015 crashing

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Recently installed VS 2015 on my windows 8.1 system. It keeps crashing and asks me for restart/debug. Even if I just keep the IDE open and leave it idle, its crashes after some time. These are the logs i found in event viewer and couldn't figure out anything.

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25123.0, time
>   stamp: 0x56f22f32 Faulting module name:
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports_unloaded, version: 9.1.9800.0, time
>   stamp: 0x3d802612 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x0001fe34
>   Faulting process id: 0xf04 Faulting application start time:
>   0x01d1c362423c7d96 Faulting application path: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe Faulting
>   module path: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports Report Id:
>   1381257e-2f56-11e6-8282-648099c4e3f6 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> Faulting application name: StandardCollector.Service.exe, version:
>   14.0.25123.0, time stamp: 0x56f2261c Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18233, time stamp: 0x56bb4ebb Exception code:
>   0xc000000d Fault offset: 0x0000000000102ab0 Faulting process id:
>   0x1ae0 Faulting application start time: 0x01d1c3404a4d066d Faulting
>   application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Team Tools\DiagnosticsHub\Collector\StandardCollector.Service.exe Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll Report Id:
>   f0ec5ba2-2f50-11e6-8282-648099c4e3f6 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: remove CrystalReports it causes the VS crash (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports_unloaded)

Comment: I could not find that in my VS extensions or control panel.